# Unable to Start daemon process & Gradle syncing is too slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I Updated my Android Studio and as well I keep getting this error when I launch any project ...

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Nerd\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7.1-bin\bwlcbys1h7rz3272sye1xwiv6\gradle-6.7.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000080000000, 268435456, 0) failed; error='The paging file is too small for this operation to complete' (DOS error/errno=1455)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 268435456 bytes for Failed to commit area from 0x0000000080000000 to 0x0000000090000000 of length 268435456.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nerd\.gradle\daemon\6.7.1\hs_err_pid21920.log

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory
```

I thought maybe my C: drive has insufficient space but I cleaned lost of unuseful files. 
and I can't figure out why my C: drive had 32 GB Space and while Gradle is Building it's just becomes Low space and when the Gradle synch finish unsuccessfully it has 7.2 GB space!

I just recently install Unity game engine and used the Android Studio SDK directory as well. I don't know if it doesn't have any relation with the problem, but that's whole the contemporary changes to my computer.

Any Idea other than uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio will be appreciated.

Comment: How much memory do you have? it happens with lower-end devices most of the time.

Comment: Two possible issues, 1- Low Memory 2- Internet issue.

Comment: I have 16 GB of Ram and 250 GB SSD Internal Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Your error states that the daemon exited because there was **insufficient memory**. Here, it is referring to the RAM, and not the hard disk. Add this to gradle.properties file, create one if it's not present,

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512M -Xmx5G
```